# Disable all tests in my class [TestClass]

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

Can I disable all my tests in my class?

I am using namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;`

Single tests can be ignored with the `[Ignored]` attribute.

Comment: If the tests are failing, fix them or remove them. Don't ignore them.

Comment: @DanielMann Sometimes the tests cannot be fixed (at that point in time) and you don't want to remove them and lose them all. For example, we had a few tests that had a Nuget dependency that had been deprecated, and the recommended nuget package meant to replace the old one was not supported for C# at the time. This caused issues for us on our build machines. We had a task to fix the tests once we were able to but in the mean time the ignore attribute was very useful.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this by placing the Ignore attribute on your class. If you look at the documentation of the [IgnoreAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.ignoreattribute.aspx) you will see that it can be applied both to methods and to classes.